# Convert objects in ArrayList to String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm trying to return a concatenated string from objects which have been placed in an ArrayList.

```
public String displayProperties() {
    StringBuilder propertyList = new StringBuilder();
    properties.forEach(propertyList::append);
    String e = propertyList.toString();
    return e;
}
```

When I return e. I get an object reference.

properties is defined as:

```
List<House> properties = new ArrayList <House>();
```

Comment: You have to "convert" each element in the `List` BEFORE you append it to the `StringBuilder`.  Does `House` implement `toString`?

Comment: and the question is..?

Comment: @jacob13smith that is actually valid Java code

Comment: @MadProgrammer unfortunately not. Can this be achieved by iterating over each object in the list then adding toString() to each one?

Comment: @Daniele apologies. I'm trying to print a String containing each variable that's in the House objects in the list.

Comment: as suggested by MadProgrammer, you have to override `toString()` in your house class.

Comment: and you could also convert the list to string directly, `String s=properties.toString()`

Comment: @Daniele yes their right, that's how I can do it.

Comment: @Daniele How could I access the public toString() in House from this class? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You need to write your own method `public String toString() {...}` (in the House class). See also https://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'd be all that happy with overriding `toString()` as has been suggested by the crowd. But if you wanted to do so, it is straight forward, let's assume:

```
class House{
        final String road;
        final int houseNumber;

         House(String road, int houseNumber) {
             this.road = road;
             this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
         }

         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return "House{" +
                     "road='" + road + '\'' +
                     ", houseNumber=" + houseNumber +
                     '}';
         }
     }
```

What is getting overridden here is method `toString()` from class `Object`, the root of everything (in the Java programming language). But note, if that would be the only String representation of `House`, you'd be probably in trouble as far as business requirements are concerned. Or you'd be in trouble latest when there's a 2nd representation required.

if you'd like to print something more reasonable from `House` you could do it that way, for example. (`\r\n` ... carriage return/new line):

```
        List<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();
        String ad = houses.stream()
                .map(h -> String.format("We're excessively proud to present you house nr %d at %s road\r\n", h.houseNumber, h.road))
                .reduce("", (i, j) -> i + j);
```

StringBuilder version would be like that:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(House h: houses)
{
    sb.append(String.format("We're insanely proud to present you house nr %d at %s road\r\n", h.houseNumber, h.road));
}
String ad = sb.toString();
```